# Scripted Metric Aggregation fails on unexpected = character

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

I'm trying to have some object containing all time deltas between two logs with the same recordId.

In order to do so, I'm executing the following query (Scripted Metric Aggregation) on elastic search, where the logs are, using fiddler:

```
{
    "query": {
        "exists": {
            "field": "recordId"
        }
    },
    "aggs": {
        "deltas": {
            "scripted_metric": {
                "init_script": {
                    "source": "state.deltas = {};",
                    "lang": "expression"
                },
                "map_script": {
                    "source": " if (!(doc['topic'].value in state.deltas)) { state.deltas[doc['topic'].value] = {} } state.deltas[doc['topic'].value][doc['recordId'].value] = !(doc['recordId'].value in state.deltas[doc['topic'].value]) ? doc['@timestamp'].date.millisOfDay : Math.abs(state.deltas[doc['topic'].value][doc['recordId'].value] - doc['@timestamp'].date.millisOfDay) ",
                    "lang": "expression"
                },
                "reduce_script": {
                    "source": " res = {}; for (s in states) { for(topic in Object.keys(s.deltas)) { if (!(topic in res)) { res[topic] = {} } for(recordId in Object.keys(s.deltas[topic])) { res[topic][recordId] = !(recordId in res[topic]) ? s.deltas[topic][recordId] : Math.abs(res[topic][recordId] - s.deltas[topic][recordId]) } } } return res;",
                    "lang": "expression"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But it fails because of unexpected '=' character...
Tried other ways but it always throws the same error.

What am I missing?

```
{
  "error": {
    "root_cause": [
      {
        "type": "lexer_no_viable_alt_exception",
        "reason": "lexer_no_viable_alt_exception: null"
      }
    ],
    "type": "search_phase_execution_exception",
    "reason": "all shards failed",
    "phase": "query",
    "grouped": true,
    "failed_shards": [
      {
        "shard": 0,
        "index": "il0:il1-sys-logs-2020.10.07",
        "node": "5bmIYI_iSVCtx41qEEbASg",
        "reason": {
          "type": "script_exception",
          "reason": "compile error",
          "script_stack": [
            "state.deltas = {};",
            "             ^---- HERE"
          ],
          "script": "state.deltas = {};",
          "lang": "expression",
          "caused_by": {
            "type": "parse_exception",
            "reason": "parse_exception: unexpected character '= ' on line (1) position (13)",
            "caused_by": {
              "type": "lexer_no_viable_alt_exception",
              "reason": "lexer_no_viable_alt_exception: null"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    ],
    "caused_by": {
      "type": "lexer_no_viable_alt_exception",
      "reason": "lexer_no_viable_alt_exception: null"
    }
  },
  "status": 500
}
```

Comment: What's the reason for not using `painless` instead of `expression`?

Comment: Just because its syntax is more convenient when handling dates

Comment: Looks like you're using lucene date expressions (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-scripting-expression.html#_date_field_api) which are valid in painless too! Try it with painless -- I know more about it than `expression` and can maybe help.